# Fixed header on each page

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm making a one-page parallax website with a fixed header. I wanted to know if there's any way to fix the header just on top of all of the sections so when i scroll it stays on top but when i move to a different section it appears again on top of that section.

Comment: I **don't** recommend Fixed header to anyone, except if you can fix this on mobile devices.

Even some proffesional websites has errors...

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: fixed` in your CSS should keep the element at a particular location in the viewport.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
position: fixed;
```

for the header div in css.

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<div id="Header">
</div>
<div id="body">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#Header
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#333;
}
#body
{
    border:5px solid #1bafcc;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:10px;
    width:1000px;
    padding-top:50px;
    height:600px;
    z-index:-600;
    position:relative;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7jdn/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what he is asking is for several fixed headers depending on scroll position in the page, in which the next section would overtake the previous section.

To have several fixed headers stick on scroll, you will need javascript.  If you were just doing one header per page, it would not be an issue.  There are some experimental css positions in play, but they are very early and browser support is still poor.

see here [Sticky Positions](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/)